# how to write a shell script to pack folder and some specific file in the folder?

Tags: shell

I have a shell script which I use to pack some file into the tar format

Let's say I'm going to pack the file `/www/b.php`

Inside the `www` folder there are some files which include `b.php`, but I only want to pack `b.php`.

I also want to have the `www` folder included in my package. Of course, the folder should have the same permission as the original one.

Therefore, how do I write a shell script to do that? What is the syntax?

Comment: What is the point for just pack a single file?

Comment: But is not tar packing with relative path already?

Comment: the point for just packing a single file is only example for ur reference, actually im doing a deployment system, and pack some files but not all

Comment: tar has an option to grab the list of files to build an archive out of from a file, use that

Comment: fge - would u mind to tell me the option

Answer (score 1):

```
tar cPf package.tar /www/b.php
```